# Add CABasicAnimation animation to collectionView iphone13Pro will freeze or jitter in animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
animation.duration = 0.6
animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.3, 1.3, 0.3, 1)
animation.fromValue = CGPoint(x: collectionView.layer.position.x , y:       collectonView.layer.position.y + 250)
animation.toValue = CGPoint(x: collectionView.layer.position.x , y:  collectionView.layer.position.y)
collection.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
```

when controlPoints y-axis exceeds 1，13Pro and iPadPro will jitter.

But when I use CAKeyFrameAnimation , I try to simulate  points on the Bezier curve

```
let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    animation.duration = 0.6
    animation.values = [CGPoint(x: collectionView.layer.position.x , y: collectionView.layer.position.y + 250),
                        CGPoint(x: collectionView.layer.position.x , y: collectionView.layer.position.y + 142),
                        CGPoint(x: collectionView.layer.position.x , y: collectionView.layer.position.y + 61),
                        CGPoint(x: collectionView.layer.position.x , y: collectionView.layer.position.y + 15),
                        CGPoint(x: collectionView.layer.position.x , y: collectionView.layer.position.y - 3.1),
                        CGPoint(x: collectionView.layer.position.x , y: collectionView.layer.position.y - 7.4),
                        CGPoint(x: collectionView.layer.position.x , y: collectionView.layer.position.y - 6.4),
                        CGPoint(x: collectionView.layer.position.x , y: collectionView.layer.position.y - 4.2),
                        CGPoint(x: collectionView.layer.position.x , y: collectionView.layer.position.y - 2.1),
                        CGPoint(x: collectionView.layer.position.x , y: collectionView.layer.position.y - 0.4),
                        CGPoint(x: collectionView.layer.position.x , y: collectionView.layer.position.y)];
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    collectionView.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
```

animation is executed normally.

is it a ProMotion Refresh issue?
how to fix it?